# Log tomcat logs to rsyslog

Tags: java, tomcat, log4j, log4j2, rsyslog

I have a java web application that runs with tomcat7 and logs with log4j. I want to send my logs to rsyslog.

I have use the appeneder in my log4j.xml file.

```
<appender name="syslog" class="org.apache.log4j.net.SyslogAppender">
          <param name="Facility" value="USER"/>
          <param name="SyslogHost" value="localhost"/>
      <param name="Threshold" value="WARN"/>
      <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
         <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{MMM dd HH:mm:ss} MYAPP: %-5p %m%n"/>
 </layout>
</appender>
```

But I still don't see the logs that I've implemented in my java application in rsyslog. I can see them in catalina.out but not on rsyslog.

Do I have to define new rules for rsyslog configuration?

Thanks in advance.

Updated log4j.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">
<log4j:configuration debug="true"
 xmlns:log4j='http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/'>


<appender name="System.out" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
    <param name="Target" value="System.out" />
    <param name="ConversionPattern" 
      value="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n" />
    </layout>
</appender>

<appender name="SYSLOG" class="org.apache.log4j.net.SyslogAppender">
    <param name="SyslogHost" value="localhost"/>
    <param name="Facility" value="LOCAL1"/>
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
    <param name="ConversionPattern" 
      value="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n" />
    </layout>
</appender>

<!-- for package specific --> 
<!-- <category name ="my.package" /> -->
<logger name ="Logger">
        <level value ="debug" />
</logger>       

<!-- root logger --> 
<root>
     <level value="info"/>
      <appender-ref ref="SYSLOG"/>
</root>
```

Comment: defining an appender is not going to do the job, you have to use it as well like >

        
  <root>
    <priority value ="info" />
    <appender-ref ref="ShortFormattedConsoleAppender"/>
  </root>

Comment: yes I have <level value="DEBUG" /> and <appender-ref ref="console" /> between my <root> tags.

Comment: post your complete log4j.xml

Comment: added the log4j.xml file.

Comment: I don't see any problem with your log4j configuration, so I guess you need to check your syslog daemon configuration. An interesting point to start is http://help.papertrailapp.com/kb/configuration/configuring-remote-syslog-from-unixlinux-and-bsdos-x/ and you need to check how LOCAL1 is being logged in your syslog daemon.

Comment: Thanks! I'll look into it and update with either another question or hopefully an answer.